# Display 50 if attribute value is blank in backend

Tags: attributes, price, product-view, custom-attributes

please visit this : [link](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/chhota-bheem-tt-bats-green-blue-2-tt-bats.html)

search for **Rs 10** using **ctrl + F**

here i am  displaying attribute value [i.e 10 ] ,

1) If we entered value as "0" in textfield than we displaying "free delivery" as [here](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/chhota-bheem-keychain.html)

If there is no value entered in textfield [attribute value], **than i want to display "50"** = > **Selling price + Rs 50 Delivery**. but now its displaying like this : [link](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/full-of-power-chhota-bheem-mug.html)

attribute code : "mp_local_shipping_charge"

**Price.phtml**

```
<span class="price-label"><?php echo $_specialPriceStoreLabel ?></span>
<span class="price" id="product-price-<?php echo $_id ?>
<?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>"
<?php if($helperSettings->isShowOfferPrice($_product)):?> itemprop="lowPrice"<?php endif;?>>
<?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_finalPrice, false) ?>
<?php $deliveryPrice = $_product->getData("mp_local_shipping_charge");
if($deliveryPrice == 0){ ?>
<p class="sell_price"><?php echo "Selling Price (Free Delivery )"; ?> </p>
<?php }elseif(empty($deliveryPrice)) { ?>
<p class="sell_price"><?php echo "Selling Price + Rs 50 Delivery "; ?> </p>
<?php }else { ?>
<p class="sell_price"><?php echo "Selling Price"; ?>
<?php echo "+ Rs " . $_product->getData("mp_local_shipping_charge") . " Delivery "; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: What is type and default value for `mp_local_shipping_charge` attribute?

Comment: its textfield type attribute

Comment: pls let me know if you need other information

Comment: Try to echo `var_dump($deliveryPrice);` before `if{}else{}` condition, and see what will be the result.

Comment: its displying like this : string(2) "10 infront of RS

Comment: I won't able to see same info on : http://test.collagekingapp.com/chhota-bheem-keychain.html

Comment: please check here : [link](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101650/display-50-if-attribute-value-is-blank-in-backend) i updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first thing i had to do was a little cleanup, so here is the readable version of your above code:

```
<span class="price-label"><?php echo $_specialPriceStoreLabel ?></span>
<span class="price" id="product-price-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>"<?php if($helperSettings->isShowOfferPrice($_product)):?> itemprop="lowPrice"<?php endif;?>>
    <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_finalPrice, false) ?>
    <?php $deliveryPrice = $_product->getData("mp_local_shipping_charge") ?>
    <?php if($deliveryPrice == 0): ?>
        <p class="sell_price"><?php echo "Selling Price (Free Delivery )"; ?> </p>
    <?php elseif(empty($deliveryPrice)): ?>
        <p class="sell_price"><?php echo "Selling Price + Rs 50 Delivery "; ?> </p>
    <?php else: ?>
        <p class="sell_price"><?php echo "Selling Price"; ?>
        <?php echo "+ Rs " . $_product->getData("mp_local_shipping_charge") . " Delivery "; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

The problem is, that the first `if` is using `==` operator, which does not check for the type. So in php, `0 == ""` is true.

To solve this, you can use the `===` operator and instead of checking for 0 (which is a number) you check for "0" as a string or whatever is exactly in the attribute (you can get the type and value with var_dump($var) )

In Short, this should do it:

```
<span class="price-label"><?php echo $_specialPriceStoreLabel ?></span>
<span class="price" id="product-price-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>"<?php if($helperSettings->isShowOfferPrice($_product)):?> itemprop="lowPrice"<?php endif;?>>
    <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_finalPrice, false) ?>
    <?php $deliveryPrice = $_product->getData("mp_local_shipping_charge") ?>
    <?php if($deliveryPrice === "0"): ?>
        <p class="sell_price"><?php echo "Selling Price (Free Delivery )"; ?> </p>
    <?php elseif(empty($deliveryPrice)): ?>
        <p class="sell_price"><?php echo "Selling Price + Rs 50 Delivery "; ?> </p>
    <?php else: ?>
        <p class="sell_price"><?php echo "Selling Price"; ?>
        <?php echo "+ Rs " . $_product->getData("mp_local_shipping_charge") . " Delivery "; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot boss : ) When you gave answer, for sure it will work...

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just make default value equal 50. So then if any other values is enter, in this case 0, it will be changed.

From my personnel experience it's always better to have some value to be calculated off and it's easier to filter in the backend.

Comment: yes, problem with client..... they wanted something like this

Comment: You missing a little bit as Blank and 0 are the same value. Check this http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php . You might need to write your code to elseif($deliveryPrice == "") You might also want to check you operators. http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/php-questions/difference-between-and-in-php/